# Unable to import hiredis using cmake in c project?

Tags: c, redis, cmake, hiredis

The content of my `Findhiredis.cmake` is

```
# Try to find hiredis
# Once done, this will define
#
# HIREDIS_FOUND        - system has hiredis
# HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS - hiredis include directories
# HIREDIS_LIBRARIES    - libraries need to use hiredis

if(HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS AND HIREDIS_LIBRARIES)
  set(HIREDIS_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
else()
  find_path(
    HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES hiredis/hiredis.h
    HINTS ${HIREDIS_ROOT_DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include)

  find_library(
    HIREDIS_LIBRARY
    NAMES hiredis
    HINTS ${HIREDIS_ROOT_DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

  set(HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS ${HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIR})
  set(HIREDIS_LIBRARIES ${HIREDIS_LIBRARY})

  include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
  find_package_handle_standard_args(
    hiredis DEFAULT_MSG HIREDIS_LIBRARY HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIR)

  mark_as_advanced(HIREDIS_LIBRARY HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIR)
endif()
```

and i am using the following code the build

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_library( microhttpd REQUIRED )
find_package(hiredis REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( project ${HIREDIS_LIBRARIES} )
```

and the include in main file is `#include <hiredis.h>` . The error i keep on getting is

```
main.c:5:10: fatal error: hiredis.h: No such file or directory
#include <hiredis.h>
```

Not sure where i am going wrong. The script to find hiredis package is taken from redox github repository and i already validated that the package is installed. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Are you providing a value for HIREDIS_ROOT to your cmake call (e.g. `cmake -DHIREDIS_ROOT=<path>` ...)? And where do you define the target (e.g. add_library or add_executable)? Cannot recognise it from your build description.

Comment: I meant `HIREDIS_ROOT_DIR` in the call to cmake.

Comment: @vre no, but i installed redis from fedora package manager and everything is installed in standard path.. i am not that well versed with cmake so not sure what to pass.. add_executable is there, just posted the relevant part of snippet.

Comment: Now I probably see what went wrong. Can you try to `#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>` in your main.cpp? I think the include is installed under `/usr/include/hiredis/hiredis.h` and your `Findhiredis.cmake` returns `/usr/include` in `HIREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS`. So you need the relative path to that directory.